# Deploy to AWS Lambda with Grunt

Tags: amazon-web-services, gruntjs, aws-lambda, web-deployment

I think it's a simple question, I've set up an application in NodeJs to deploy to Amazon's Lambda with [Grunt AWS Lambda](https://github.com/Tim-B/grunt-aws-lambda), the deploy is running fine until the time of upload, which returns an error prohibiting the application from being longer than 50MB. This application uses the Chrome to generate PDFs, so the application gets more than 50mb. Is there any way to run deploy with files larger than this size?

Thanks!

Comment: An alternative would be to upload the sourcecode first to S3 and then update the function code with S3 settings. But this is a feature which isn't supported by that library you are using (so far as I can see)

Answer (score 0):

try upload zip via AWS S3. you can deploy until 250MB.
https://hackernoon.com/exploring-the-aws-lambda-deployment-limits-9a8384b0bec3

Comment: Thank you! Yeah, I saw this post, but this way I can't use the deploy with Grunt =(

Comment: I found the PR about s3 upload on grunt aws lambda. however, not updated since 2017 may.
https://github.com/Tim-B/grunt-aws-lambda/pull/106  

you should use another way.